# chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived cannot change headers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to remove `content-security-policy` header It work on other websites but not on `tiktok.com`. but I can see in debugger that the headers is modified.

`manifest.json`

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "test ex",
    "short_name": "test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "test",

    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },

    "permissions": [
        "declarativeContent",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "https://www.tiktok.com/*",
        "tabs",
        "webNavigation",
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

`background.js`

```
var webReqOpts = {
    urls: ["https://www.tiktok.com/*"]
};

function modifyResponseHeaders(response) {
    if (response.type == "main_frame" || response.type == "sub_frame") {
        var headers = response.responseHeaders,
            newHeaders = [],
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i) {
            if (!['content-security-policy', 'content-security-policy-report-only'].includes(headers[i].name.toLowerCase())) {
                newHeaders.push(headers[i]);
            }

        }
        return {
            responseHeaders: newHeaders
        };
    }

}

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(modifyResponseHeaders, webReqOpts, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);
```

Comment: Try `"*://*.tiktok.com/*"`

Comment: tried, no effect

Comment: Assuming you've reloaded the extension on chrome://extensions page, try adding `"extraHeaders"` to the last array in addListener.

Comment: after modification I always reload the extension, `"extraHeaders"` still not help. strange I cannot change any header on tiktok.

Comment: Open `chrome://policy` and click `Show more` to the right of `ExtensionSettings`. It may have runtime_blocked_hosts for tiktok.

Comment: `ExtensionSettings` has no value, @wOxxOm thanks

Comment: Then it's because another extension changes the headers earlier. Try disabling everything or try making a new profile with just your own extension.

Comment: created new profile, no other extension but still no luck

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome then. Do you open tiktok.com or www.tiktok.com?

Comment: opening  tiktok.com will redirect to www. tiktok.com

Comment: I open www.tiktok.com

Comment: This code actually works for me so apparently it's a problem in devtools not showing the correct headers.